# Typescript constructor parameters based on class & subclass properties

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Let's suppose I'm looking to reuse some basic constructor in subclasses but its parameter will depend on the properties of the subclass.

Here is a basic (non-working) example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
class Foo {
    a: string = 'a'

    constructor(params?: { [key in keyof this]: this[key] }) { // this doesn't work as 'this' is not permited static members. 
        Object.assign(this, params)
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    b: string = 'b'

    // constructor inherited accepting { a: string, b: string }
}

const myFoo = new Foo({ a: 'foo' })
const myBar = new Bar({ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' })
```

Is there some kind of way to do it in TS ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXpgFzQgBcAnASwDsBzaAXmgHIx6MNtph5yjiBXYQ+MQAUABzDEwAWwgB+fMmgBtANYBTAJ7QK0NevgAzaIQAWpCAF18Jsyo3noAXwCUKaAHo3R0zAAm8VRDk9ITQAO6Cyjgwwd70WjDk8CEiqsSSpISqPgSEYISkwNCSqpIARqkQAHTQrGzYAPKlAFaq-JWQEKSU5ELWEAA00GIS0k61WA4Yk+gYoB3QAELi0KoAHpnkPjAISGiY2KX43BTUdPSlzDP7WB7snNx8AsRa5MapGVk4wMCqIvlUrjwOTIVEGh2BJ0cUxY6A4XBCknUO1o0HIqlCcEQQgUQPo+kQcWcs3uCPUS2edDRGPJ2Jw+DxBLB9NK4kJTiAA)

Answer (score 0):

For `Foo`, you could use `params?: Foo` and then `new Foo({a: "ayy"})` would work, but `Bar` would expect a `Foo`, not a `Bar`.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's anything you can do to change that other than provide a constructor in `Bar`. That constructor doesn't have to do much of course, just `super(params)`.

```typescript
class Foo {
    a: string = "a";

    constructor(params?: Foo) {
        Object.assign(this, params);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    b: string = "b";

    constructor(params?: Bar) {
        super(params);
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXpgFzQgBcAnASwDsBzaAXmgCIx6BuDDbaYeco4gV2CF4xABQAHMMTABbCAH58CeAEoU7DtgDyAIwBWAU0EA6SBFKVyIwgAtSEADTQJU2ctaZsAXwzf0GUKbQAEKS0PoAHoT65AAmMEpqHlja%20LwU1HT02ixsSZzcvAJCos4y8vghxKpoeRwQfGL6JZJlbupYvr5AA)

It would be nice if `params?: typeof this` (or some other derivative of it) would work (and handle the change in meaning across subclasses), but that isn't the case currently.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for but you can use generics. Subclass type will be passed to base class as a generic when defining a new subclass.

```ts
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K;
}[keyof T];
type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
type DefaultFoo = Foo<any>;

class Foo<T extends Foo = DefaultFoo> { // Can't default to Foo here, it errors: Type parameter 'T' has a circular default.(2716)
    a: string = 'a'

    constructor(params?: Partial<NonFunctionProperties<T>>) {
        Object.assign(this, params)
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
    b: string = 'b'
}

new Foo({ a: 'foo' }) // no error
new Bar({ a: 'foo', }) // no error
new Bar({ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }) // no error
new Foo({ b: 1 }) // error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Partial<NonFunctionProperties<DefaultFoo>>'.
new Bar({ a: 1 }) // error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
new Bar({ ab: '' }) // error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ab' does not exist in type 'Partial<NonFunctionProperties<Bar>>'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKABBYC4J4A4FMwDkD2A7AYgV3QYygEsMAFAJ1UTNmQEMBbBAZwB4AVAPjAF4wBvUJEgBtANJhC6MAGsEMVADMwbALoAuZWJVgEADygJ0AEyZgc+IhjAB+MOgQA3BGTAbRAbkGQAvsNnylVU9wSFhEFAxzAmJ0ckpnImZ2Ll4SQjxpdgAaCKxcaNIKKhoGJM4OYKEwpAARBAVabAAbKExUVB4zdpZadBgK0C8IPCbaJlM21HYdfUMTLo7eOobm1vauPjAAei2wAGFegHIoMCN6xpboDsmwAAtnBBzCE+cKMiYNNngkOFoyUoMLkObEOdzGYFoYDwhDIeGaf1O51WADoABQAJgA7ABGABsAEohkIIRomFAyJIAOadQ60Q6DELEqEYMlkbAEVBkVG-f70JjWDQkP5EWhNFhoPIWGJxYqEMocDj4-hEpkQADyACMAFYIAjIsZMQiU9CoqC3QhMHI8hhMQmM4neImOkBEkYGsAAIQRegMxgm3S9ZA2KsgGtJ5KpNI19PtzqJ9gA7gtUZtaBpDgp2qDvEqdnYOq9OfGEEnAymSWAM1mcjntrt0AWyG9i6W-uW05XM6hDjkw5WNX9s7n643m-bE8nNn3sWBa3nC2QNJqdQQwE1ns5RWB6LQYGAME090xENCFHvpA2E1I4EUEnLLRDjP3QUZUMx8y9dBaTpJoN9K0K1CEKK4qRPklixLeQFJMsFxrKgCqHMiLaem2qYaDOc67Aunz-oc6DYPQGrOKCFofhC4xGugtAak0SBQB01SVqyVJIShZapn2hxDnWOhNpyS7arqJzroCW47nuB5HiehBnjIl7XlBiQPr0RiVjRL5vqYDaft+EhSExhyASKYoSlEEEyneSSBohyEgEAA)

For details about `NonFunctionProperties` see [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#example-2)